# Create TableView after [TabBarController]->[NavigationController]->[TableView]

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, push, navigationcontroller

Here's what I've created : [TabBarController]->[NavigationController]->[TableView]. I want to create an new [TableView] that will be pushed when I select a cell in the first UITableView.
I tried with a pushViewController method. It works but I can't go back to my first TableView (there is no navigation bar). I also tried with a navigationBar between the 2 UITableView but I received the message "cannot push to a navigation bar".
Can anyone guide me ? Thanks

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:TableView2 animated:YES];
```

(self is my first UITableView)

Comment: Please a code where you call `pushViewController`

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:TableView2 animated:YES]; (self is my first TableView)

Comment: You're mixing views and view controllers. Is tableView2 your view controller?

Comment: I have 2 views (TableView1 et TableView2) et 2 view controllers(navigation controller and tab bar controller)

Comment: You need to have UITableViewController containing your TableView2. And push that controller into Navigation controller and not the view itself.

Comment: yes sorry I am mixing view and view controllers. I have only view controllers.

Comment: Then you need to post some code on how exactly you're creating second view controller. If you just call `push...` it should do exactly that, and you should still have navigation bar.

Comment: I created the TabBarController(embedded), NavigationController(embedded)and TableViewcontroller in the interface builder. The aim is to display a new TableView when you click on a cell in the TableViewcontroller. That's why I created a new TableViewController and tried to push it.But maybe the best solution is to display a new TableView in the first TableViewcontroller. What do you think?

Comment: like mentioned by [sha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/274519/sha),  can you post the code which you used to create the `TableView2 View Controller` ? and where exactly are you writing this line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:TableView2 animated:YES];` ?

Comment: Please post relevant code so as to analyse it and we can provide you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController`should exist before first`TableViewController`. When the cell on first`TableView`is pressed, it should send an event to`TableView`making use of delegate. After, push the second`TableViewController`. After that, you can pop back to first`TableViewController`from the second`TableViewController`.